# Why does some IE9 supports css selectors, but some others doesn't?

Tags: internet-explorer-9, css-selectors

IE9 on my desktop supports css selectors perfect.
But same IE9 on other computer does not.

I've tested on http://tools.css3.info/selectors-test/test.html.

Both computers are running Windows7.
Why does it happen in the same browser, same OS?

Answer (score 2):

IE9 should behave the in same way regardless what machine it's on. The only way you could get variable behavior like this is if you have a different *browser mode*, or *document mode* instructing the browser to behave as though it were an older version. Other than this, the document would have to be in compatibility mode, either by the direction of the user, or by being placed on the Compatibility View List.

Press F12 to open up your Developer Tools. In there you will see the Browser Mode, and the Document Mode at the top-right of the tools. I'm using IE10, but you can see below what I'm referring to:

[image]

Further Reading: [Compatibility Modes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh920756%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: +1. Opening dev tools (F12) will immediately show document mode on top of the dev window.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought would be that on one of the machines IE is probably [running in compatability mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg622935%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and the css selectors you are using dont work when its in that rendering mode.